# Transitions translateX not working only on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css-transitions

I have something like this: http://dabblet.com/gist/5939428

Why this working on all browsers (even IE) excepts Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you pls try this.

Here I have added z-index:1:

```
.grid figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #1d1d1b;
    color: #fff;
        z-index:1; 
}
```

and here I set z-index value ten(10).

```
.cs-style-2 figure .cat, .cs-style-2 figure .cat img {
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    position: relative;
}
```

Its working for me in both firefox and chrome

Comment: Edit: almost works ;)

But links are not clickable :/

http://jsfiddle.net/ctDZy/

Comment: Done :)

I gave a link to jsfiddle because then dabblet did not work;)

Comment: I have update my answer(Just changed z-index and added position relative in cs-style-2 figure .cat, .cs-style-2 figure .cat img).